# Why does it hold $\operatorname{E}[Y\mid\mathcal{F}]=\operatorname{E}[Y\mid Y]=Y$, if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$ be a probability space
- $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$
- $Y\in\mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$ be measurable wrt $\mathcal{F}$

Then, $$\operatorname{E}[Y\mid\mathcal{F}]=\operatorname{E}[Y\mid Y]=Y$$

---

From the definition of conditional expectation (*see below*) it's easy to see that we've got $$\operatorname{E}[Z]=\operatorname{E}[Z'],$$ where

- $Z:=\operatorname{E}[Y\mid\mathcal{F}]$
- $Z':=\operatorname{E}[Y\mid\sigma(Y)]=\operatorname{E}[Y\mid Y]$

However, I don't see how we can conclude $Z\equiv Z'$ (almost surely) and $\operatorname{E}[Z']=Y$.

---

*Please note:*

A random variable $Z$ is called **conditional expectation** of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}$ $:\Leftrightarrow$

- $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable
- $\operatorname{E}[1_AX]=\operatorname{E}[1_AZ]$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$

We write $\operatorname{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}]=:Z$. The notation $\operatorname{E}[X\mid X']$, with $X'$ being another random variable, is a shorthand for $\operatorname{E}[X\mid\sigma(X')]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we prove that $E[Y\mid\mathscr{F}]=Y$ whenever $Y$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable. For this, you only need to demonstrate that $Y$ satisfies the two given requirements:

- $Y$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable: this is given;
- $E[1_AY]=E[1_AY]$ for all $A\in\mathscr{F}$: this is trivial.

Next, consider $E[Y\mid Y]$. Let $\mathscr{G}=\sigma(Y)$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$. Of course, $Y$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, so by the result just proved, we have $E[Y\mid Y]=E[Y|\mathscr{G}]=Y$. We conclude
$$
E[Y\mid\mathscr{F}]=Y=E[Y\mid Y]\quad\text{whenever }Y\text{ is }\mathscr{F}\text{-measurable}.
$$

Comment: As you have shown, the statement is trivial. It seems like I was confused about the involved concepts, which are still new for me.

Comment: @Oxbadfood: this looks like an exercise that follows soon after the introduction of conditional expectation. For these, usually you just need to go back to the definition. One good text for this is Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Z$ and $Z'$ are two versions of $E(Y|\mathcal F)$. Look at $X:=Z-Z'$. By definition of conditional expectation, $E(X1_A)=0$ for every $A\in\mathcal F$. Apply this to the set $X>\varepsilon$:
$$0 = E(X1_{\{X>\varepsilon\}})\ge\varepsilon P(X>\varepsilon)$$
Conclude that $P(X>\varepsilon) =0$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Finally use the fact that $\{X>\frac1n\}\uparrow\{X>0\}$ to conclude $P(X>0)=0$. Similarly $P(X<0)=0$.